# Why does setting textview text inside a fragment result in a crash?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to have a TextView always say the current date. However, the setText method crashes the program with a NullPointerExeption... As of now the date isn't the problem - I'm only using regular text to test it. I don't know where the best place is to put my code, so I decided to use onActivityCreated. What's going on, and also is there anything I can do to make my code better? *Note, the textview is in fragment_page, not fragment_page 2, as this is the first tab in sliding tab layout.

Fragment Class

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    if(mPage < 2) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_2, container, false);
    }


    return view;
}

//@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    /*Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");


       */
        TextView textView = (TextView)     getView().findViewById(R.id.current_date);
        textView.setText("sadFace"); //null pointer exeption on this line
  }
}
```

Fragment XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="239dp"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/current_date"
                android:text="Today is January 1st, 2015"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the line

`TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.current_date);`

which worked by itself, but resulted in null pointer. I changed `getView()` to `getActivity()` and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.

Move the block of code inside `onCreateView`, if current_date is only in `fragment_page`, then you should also move them inside the `IF` condition.

```
    View view;
    if(mPage < 2) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.current_date);
        textView.setText("sadFace");
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_2, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: I had it there before, and because it was crashing I moved it farther down the life cycle of the fragment to see. However, doing it again just now I noticed that the crash occurs of the TextView instantiation line, and not the textView.setText... still a null pointer exeption though.

Comment: current_date is in layout fragment_page right? Can you do a debug and see if your view inflation actually returns anything? If your crash occurs at the findViewById line, it might means your view is null.

Comment: The view? It does return something (although the TextView has no effect on it...) In commenting out the Textview, everything works as expected. The way it is above, just commenting the setText works. Here, I have to comment the textView itself. Is there a reason for the change in where the error occurs?